# Vue + Laravel: Still use old endpoint pagination?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on a Laravel app that has used Blade files for a while.  We are switching part of the app to use Vue now.  One of the endpoints we had used pagination with a `page` parameter at the end of it.
For example: `/store/api/users?page=1` and each page would show 20 users -- sort of like a lazyLoad.
Does this make sense to keep it like this for Vue?  With Vue, shouldn't the endpoint just get me ALL the users and then I can do what I want with that data?

Comment: That's fine, yes. However, you should be aware of the fact that as your data grows, the loading of that page will be slower. As you add more complex relationships, the loading of that page will be slower. Etc.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks!  So what is the best approach then?  Isn't it an antipattern to have the backend control the pagination with frontend frameworks?

Comment: Not always. Especially when you're dealing with 10's of millions of rows. However, until you really start to see a degrading of performance, don't worry about it. My mantra is get it working, and when you start making money, go back and refactor.

Comment: thank you @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not query all the data and return to vuejs. If your data is huge then you will be in big trouble with slower performance. So, it's always a good idea to use Larave's paginations even while you are responding json instead of view.

For example when you were using blade, you were doing something like:

```
$users = User::where('column', $value)->paginate();

return view('user.index', compact('user'));
```

Right? Now you are using `Vuejs` and still have you covered with it's nice length aware paginator instance. So, now you can do something like:

```
$users = User::where('column', $value)->paginate();
return $users;
```

This Will return all paginations meta data like, total page, current page etc.
So that, you can manipulate those data perfectly in vuejs.